# Unable to submit form with prevent default enabled

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, form-submit

I have a code to be executed before the actual submission of the form. I have ajax call , after which based on the result, the form submission has to happen, which is not working.

```
    <form id="myform" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="test" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>

    <script>
    $(document).on("submit", '#myform', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var form    = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (response) 
        {
            if(response    ==  1)
            {
                form.submit();
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: be specific.."not working"..wht's your error?

Comment: what's the response?

Comment: Form submission is happening in the else condition as well. @Vimal

Comment: what is the value of `'url'`? Did you check the value of 'response'? whether it is 1?

Comment: Do you really want to submit the form as soon as someone clicks inside it? `$('#myForm').on('submit'...` would seem more appropriate

Comment: change `$('#myform').on('click', function (event)` to `$('#submit').on('click', function (event)` then this should be at first line ` e.preventDefault();`

Comment: the value of the response should be 1 and not an object

Comment: this does not make sense at all `if(response   ==  1)
            {
                form.submit();
            }
            else
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }`

Comment: why are you submitting the form after the ajax call. whats the point of the ajax call?? Also you do not pass any data via your AJAX

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile if I give e.preventDefault() before Ajax, then form submit doesn't happen (The IF condition doesn't work)

Comment: its `event.preventDefault();` the form will be submitted without refreshing/reloading the page u can see that in the console or in the network tab @Steffi

Comment: @Steffi check the answers below one of them should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I myself found the answer for this question.

Make sure you do not have an "NAME" attribute with "submit" as attribute's value.

Below is the code snippet, which worked absolutely fine.

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="test" />
    <input type="submit" name="submitForm" id="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

<script>
$(document).on("submit", '#myform', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var form    = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?=PATH_SITE?>actions/qa/qaActions.php?act=checkSessionExist",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (response) 
        {
            if(response    ==  1)
            {
                form.trigger('submit');
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what u really wanna achieve with this

```
if(response   ==  1)
            {
                form.submit();
            }
            else
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
```

it does not make sense at all, and its hard to understand what you want as you do not really respond on comments above.

I'm not sure if you have some kind of validation if its for validation you can use [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate in the front end then also validate with server side on the server.

Plus you not sending any data to the server side.

This is how your script should look :

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="test" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

<script>
$('#myform').on('submit', function (event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var formdata    = $('#myform').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        type: 'POST',
        data : formdata,
        dataType : 'json',
        encode : true,
        success: function (response) 
        {
            if(response   ==  "What you expected")
            {
               // DO something else
            }
            else
            {
                // Write the error back to the user in some div
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Edit : If you want a validation before submit you can use the library I have mentioned above, this is how you would do it

```
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

<script>

$('#myform').validate({

    rules :{

        username :{

            required : true,
        }
    },

    messages :{

        username : {

            required : "Enter username",
        }
    },

    submitHandler : sendData

});

function sendData(){

    var formdata    = $('#myform').serialize();
     $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        type: 'POST',
        data : formdata,
        dataType : 'json',
        encode : true,
        success: function (response) 
        {
            if(response   ==  "What you expected")
            {
               // DO something else
            }
            else
            {
                // Write the error back to the user in some div
            }
        }
    });


    return false; //prevent form traditional submission    
}
</script>
```

Also don't forget to validate in the server side as well

**More Edit**

You are saying the reason you wanna send the request and send it again is because you wanna check if a session exists, well you can do that before you can even show the form to the user, if the session exists then show the form or else show error or something

this is how you will do that.

```
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<?php

    if(isset($_SESSION['name']) && !empty($_SESSION['name'])){?>

        <form id="myform" method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>

            <script>

            $('#myform').validate({

                rules :{

                    username :{

                        required : true,
                    }
                },

                messages :{

                    username : {

                        required : "Enter username",
                    }
                },

                submitHandler : sendData

            });

            function sendData(){

                var formdata    = $('#myform').serialize();
                 $.ajax({
                    url: 'url',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data : formdata,
                    dataType : 'json',
                    encode : true,
                    success: function (response) 
                    {
                        if(response   ==  "What you expected")
                        {
                           // DO something else
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Write the error back to the user in some div
                        }
                    }
                });


                return false;    
            }
            </script>
<?php

    }else{

        // the session is not set then do nothing or show error/redirect
    }
?>
```

Then on your server side you also need to check if the same session exists before accepting and processing the user input.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['name']) && !empty($_SESSION['name'])){


        //DO FORM PROCCESSING
    }else{

        echo json_encode('not set');

        // send not set back to the client and do something about that response.
    }
?>
```

Comment: But he wants to call submit again to the form's action. Isn't this going to recursively call the submit handler (ajax call etc.)?

Comment: @Wizard I think he does validation then submit again when validation rules are met... but all that can be done in a single call

Comment: Sure, but when he does submit again, the ajax call will also happen again. See my answer below, you have to unregister the submit handler before submiting to the form action.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile My requirement is I want to submit the form data, but before submitting I want to perform an ajax which internally checks something were I do not need form data. if response == 1 , then I want to submit the form. Else form submission should not happen

Comment: you can do all that in a single call, what is it that u wanna check first internally?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile It checks if a php session value exists or not

Comment: @Steffi you could do that in this page before even showing the form, if the session does not exist don't show the form at all simple

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile  My form is too lengthy. Even if I load if only session exists, before submitting the form I have to check again if session exists.

Comment: @Steffi I've updated my answer to meet your requirements please check

Comment: $(document).on("submit", '#myform', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var form    = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (response) 
        {
            if(response    ==  1)
            {
                form.submit();
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
    </script>

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Please help me in finding solution for my previous comment's code. With this code, form.submit(); is not working. The else condition works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="test" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

<script>
$('#myform').on('submit', function (event) 
{
  event.preventDefault();
   var form    = $(this);
   $.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (response) 
    {
        if(response   ==  1)
        {
            form.submit();
        }
        else
        {
            // response will be valid and the ajax will be complete here
        }
    }
  });
});
```

event should run before the ajax is called

Comment: If I have this before the ajax call, then form submission in the IF condition will not happen, only the else condition will work.

Comment: 'on submit' not 'on click'

Answer (score 0):

You should do like that

```
<script>
$('#myform').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form    = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (response) 
        {
            if(response   ==  1)
            {
                form.submit();
            }
            else
            {

                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible recursive call

Comment: You mean recursive ajax call if response is not true?

Comment: You can do it any way

Answer (score 0):

After Ajax returns successfully, unregister submit event handler to avoid recursive call and manually trigger submit event (change id and name of submit button so as to not "hide" the submit event)

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="test" />
<input type="submit" name="submitBtn" id="submitBtn" value="Save" />
</form>

<script>
$('#myform').on('submit', function (event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        type: 'POST',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(response) 
        {
            if (response ==  1)
            {
                form.off('submit');
                form.trigger('submit');
            }
        }
    });
});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also same condition below code what i use in my project.

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="test" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
<script>
$('#myform').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (response) 
        {
            if(response   ==  1)
            {
                $("#myform")[0].submit();
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: this doesn't really make sense. I think OP is very confused. Why would you submit a form after an ajax. very weird

Answer (score -1):

You code should be like this:

```
<script>
$('#submit').on('click', function (event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var form    = $("#myform");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (response) 
        {
            if(response   ==  1)
            {
                form.submit();
            }                
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Or you can use

`$( "#myform" ).submit(function( event ) {`

Comment: The `return` and the `preventDefault()` in the `success` handler isn't going to do anything as it's asynchronous

Answer (score -1):

Maybe You should run like this code where the **e.preventDefault()** called first

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="test" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

<script>
$('#myform').on('click', function (event) 
{
e.preventDefault();
var form    = $(this);
$.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (response) 
    {
        if(response   ==  1)
        {
            form.submit();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
});
 </script>
```

Comment: you can't use click on the form id. change to the id of the button. Also not my downvote